# When using SharePoint scheduling for pages, will users still see the original version of the page before the new one is published?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

For example, I have a featured post on the page for an event (v1). After the event is over, I want to schedule a new version of the page with a different featured link (v2). Will users still be able to see v1 before v2 is published? Or is the page for v1 hidden from users until the publish happens?

It is unclear in the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/schedule-a-sharepoint-page-or-news-post-to-go-live-at-a-specific-time-4b81873c-9bbc-4307-b7ea-7b6662ff1af2).

Comment: I think SharePoint site page version 1 will be visible to users until version 2 is republished.